# bento start command fails with NoClassDefFoundError DNSCheckingTool

Tags: cassandra, startup, bento

I was trying out the tutorial in https://github.com/kijiproject/kiji-schema/blob/master/kiji-schema-cassandra/cassandra_tutorial.md 
but got stuck at the place where we start the bento box. 'bento start'

It gives the following error:

```
cygpath: cannot create short name of c:\276273\WorkingFolder\Cassandra\cassandra
-bento\kiji-bento-ebi\cluster\lib\hbase-0.94.6-cdh4.3.0\logs
Running bento-cluster port configuration utility.
bento: line 620: /cygdrive/c/jdk1.6.0/bin/java: Argument list too long
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/kiji/bento/tools/
DNSCheckingTool
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.kiji.bento.tools.DNSCheckingToo
l
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
Could not find the main class: org.kiji.bento.tools.DNSCheckingTool.  Program wi
ll exit.
Local DNS check failed.  Please resolve and try again.
```

Can you please help?

Answer (score -2):

please see https://jira.kiji.org/browse/CLUSTER-39, comment invoke set `mutate_classpath` variable with `hbase_cp`.